# What is hiltViewModel lifetime in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

When I use viewModel inside Activity or Fragment it's clear, that the ViewModel is alive while the corresponding Activity/Fragment is alive.

And what about `hiltViewModel` function for Jetpack Compose. I've searched through for a while and couldn't find any documentation about that. When `BleViewModel.onCleared` is called in the example below?

```
@Composable
fun BleControl() {
    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<BleViewModel>()
    //...
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on where you write that code. Can you provide some context on where you're calling that method?

Comment: if your are using `hiltViewModel` in any composable function , then the `viewmodel` will be alive to that function only.